# Join two tables in different databases with setting limit MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

How can I set limit for inner join two tables in different databases?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM  tsv_test.title_ratings a
      INNER JOIN movielens.links b    
         ON a.tconst = b.imdbid
```

Comment: Add ORDER BY clause and LIMIT clause to your query. Or describe your task more precise - for example, show source table data and desired output.

Comment: @Akina Where is the right place of LIMIT in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about `LIMIT` [HERE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

You can also read about `ORDER BY` [HERE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/)

The syntax for them based on the SQL you posted would be:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM  tsv_test.title_ratings a
      INNER JOIN movielens.links b    
      ON a.tconst = b.imdbid
      ORDER BY a.field_name ASC
      LIMIT 10
```

**Note** that I don't know what your field names are, so I threw in `a.field_name` so you can see what the syntax looks like.